# asp.net how to show products details in listView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to view my products in list view dynamically and this is my try

```
    <asp:ListView ID="mylistView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3" 

            onitemdatabound="mylistView_ItemDataBound" 
            onitemcreated="mylistView_ItemCreated">
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lab" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MenuName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Image ID="foo" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("MenuName") %>' runat="server" />
                <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                            <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                                <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table border="0" width="300" style="display: inline-block; background-color: Lime;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a><b style="text-decoration: underline;">
                                <%# Eval("mainItem") %></b> </a>
                            <br />

                        <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                  <%#((ProductsItems)Container.DataItem).subItems%>
                            </li>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>

                            </FooterTemplate>
                      </asp:Repeater> 


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in code behind

```
     public void databind()
{
    string prod1 = "P1";
    string prod2 = "P2";
    string prod3 = "P3";
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
    list1.Add("P11");
    list1.Add("P12");
    list1.Add("P13");

    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    list1.Add("P21");
    list1.Add("P22");
    list1.Add("P23");

    List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
    list1.Add("P31");
    list1.Add("P32");
    list1.Add("P33");

     List<ProductsItems> listprodItems = new List<ProductsItems>
 {
      new ProductsItems(){ mainItem = prod1, subItems=list1 },
      new ProductsItems(){ mainItem = prod2, subItems=list2 },
      new ProductsItems(){ mainItem = prod3, subItems=list3 }
 };
    mylistView.DataSource = listprodItems;
    mylistView.DataBind();

 }
```

this is my prduct object

```
public class ProductsItems
{
   public string mainItem { get; set; }
   public List<string> subItems { get; set; }
}
```

how can i show the title for every product and its subItems using repeater under every one?
many thanks for help.

Comment: my problem is in this line  <%#((ProductsItems)Container.DataItem).subItems%>

Comment: I can not bind repeater with list of list of string.

Comment: Well, if you can focus only on that on the first place... I will write an answer...

Comment: In your next question, try to add less code, just the one you have the issue and you wish to get a solution, try to focus to the problem to help the rest people here to help you out by right see the issue you have. I hope that my answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

By using just this line `<%#((ProductsItems)Container.DataItem).subItems%>` you are stack just to render a string, so move your code to a function, and there make what you want with more flexibility, here is an example.

Add this function call (instead the previous line)...

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <br /><%# GetDetails(Container.DataItem) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and on code behind you can have something like:

```
public string GetDetails(object oItem)
    {
        // use the oData to get your Data and formats them
        var oData = (ProductsItems)oItem;

        // use a String Builder to render inside of it
        StringBuilder sbRenderOnMe = new StringBuilder();

        // oData.subItems this must be a list of strings base on your code
        foreach (var Title in oData.subItems)
        {
            sbRenderOnMe.AppendFormat("Title:{0} <br>", Title);
        }

        // and here return the results
        return sbRenderOnMe.ToString();     
    }
```

Comment: first i want to thank u again,second I applied your answer but it dropped all sub products under only the first product and no sub products under the two other products why?

Comment: @Khaledtamer Please try to understand this code, and adapt it to you logic. I am not sure what you exactly want... but if you understand the way, you simple change the function and do your logic.